# ORA-00922 encountered in Oracle 11gR2 installer

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, installation

I've just run the installer for Oracle 11gR2 on a Windows Server 2008 (64-bit) OS.

I encountered the "ORA-00922: missing or invalid option" error at the last stage of installation when it was doing something like "cloning the database". I ignored the error and then immediately got a "ORA-28000: the account is locked" error. The installer then completed successfully.

I looked in the logs for the installation ("C:\app\administrator\cfgtoollogs\dbca\orcl") and found one file named "postScripts.log" which contains these two error messages. Here is the contents of that file:

```
     1
     1
alter user CTXSYS account unlock identified by ******
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option


ERROR:
ORA-28000: the account is locked


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
dropping default lexer preference...
SP2-0640: Not connected
dropping default wordlist preference...
SP2-0640: Not connected
dropping default stoplist preference...
SP2-0640: Not connected
dropping default policy...
SP2-0640: Not connected
SP2-0640: Not connected
Enter value for lang_abbr: SP2-0310: unable to open file "C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\ctx\admin\defaults\drdefset.sql"
```

Has anyone else encountered this error before, or know how to resolve it? Will the database function correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution on my own!

It seems that there is a bug in the Oracle installer - it doesn't like it if you start your system password with a number.

I completely uninstalled Oracle using the deinstall utility and then reinstalled Oracle, this time specifying a system password beginning with a letter. This solved the problem!

I hope this helps anyone else encountering this annoying issue.